# How do I access controls from the parent page from within an ASP.NET User Control?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, user-controls, asp.net-controls

I have an ASP.NET Web Forms page `childPage.aspx` with `masterPage.aspx` as the master page. The `childPage.aspx` has a user control (`userControl.ascx`) control defined on it. Now, I am trying to access the controls on `childPage.aspx` from within the user control. I have tried a handful of different approaches:

```cs
HtmlContainerControl ProductMenu = (HtmlContainerControl)Page.FindControl("ProductMenu");

HtmlContainerControl ProductMenu = (HtmlContainerControl)this.Page.FindControl("ProductMenu");

HtmlContainerControl ProductMenu = (HtmlContainerControl)Parent.FindControl("ProductMenu");

HtmlContainerControl ProductMenu = (HtmlContainerControl)this.Parent.parent.FindControl("ContaintHolder").FindControl("ProductMenu")
```

In above code, `ProductMenu` is the `id` of the `<div runat="server" />` on `childPage.aspx`. Now, I am trying to access it from within my user control, but that fails to return the `div`.

Please help me out. How should I do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: masterPage.aspx is probably masterPage.Master, a real ASP.NET master page?

Comment: I guess, it would be much cleaner and simple, if you give the child control the references to the control you want to access from it.

Answer (score 1):

The reason this doesn't work is likely because the `FindControl()` method is not *recursive*. This is called out in the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/486wc64h(v=vs.110).aspx):

> This method will find a control only if the control is directly contained by the specified container; that is, the method does not search throughout a hierarchy of controls within controls.

So, for instance, `Page.FindControls()` will *only* search for controls listed in the `Page.Controls` collection; it won't search the `Controls` collection of each of *those* controls. As such, `Page.FindControl()` would only work if the `ProductMenu` were at the *top-level* of your ASPX page; if it is instead nested within, for instance, a `Panel` control then this code won't work.

To resolve this, you'll need to write a recursive function to crawl the control tree. For instance:

```cs
public Control FindControl(Control parentControl, string controlName) {
  foreach (var childControl in parentControl.Controls) {
    if (childControl.Id == controlName) return childControl;
    var foundControl = FindControl(childControl, controlName);
    if (foundControl != null) return childControl;
  }
  return null;
}
```

In your case, assuming you'll *always* be looking for an instance of an `HtmlContainerControl`, you could even validate the type and return a strongly typed object, should you choose. That said, if you want to keep it strongly typed while still supporting different types, you could instead use a generic:

```cs
public T FindControl<T>(Control parentControl, string controlName) where T : Control {
  foreach (var childControl in parentControl.Controls) {
    if (childControl.Id == controlName) return childControl;
    var foundControl = FindControl<T>(childControl, controlName);
    if (foundControl != null && foundControl is T) return childControl;
  }
  return null;
}
```

In addition, if you'll need to do this repeatedly, you might add this as an extension method to the `Page` class so it's easily accessible on multiple pages.